# Is there a way to optimize this date range transformation? Conditional merge in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, python-datetime

I have Sales data like this as a DataFrame, the datatype of the columns is datetime[64] of pandas:

| Shop ID | Special Offer Start | Special Offer End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | '2022-01-01' | '2022-01-03' |
| B | '2022-01-09' | '2022-01-11' |

etc.

I want to transform the data into a new binary format, that shows me the date in one column and the special offer information as 0 and 1.
The resulting table should look like this:

| Shop ID | Date | Special Offer? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | '2022-01-01' | 1 |
| A | '2022-01-02' | 1 |
| A | '2022-01-03' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-09' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-10' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-11' | 1 |

I wrote a function, which iterates every row and creates an DataFrame containing Pandas DateRange and the Special Offer information. These DataFrame are then concatenated. As you can imagine the code runs very slow.

I was thinking to append a **Special Offer?** Column to the Sales DataFrame and then joining it to a DataFrame containing all dates. Afterwards I could just fill the NaN with the dropna or fillna-function. But I couldn't find a function which lets me join on conditions in pandas.

See example below:

| Shop ID | Special Offer Start | Special Offer End | Special Offer ? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | '2022-01-01' | '2022-01-03' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-09' | '2022-01-11' | 1 |

join with (the join condition being: if **Date** between **Special Offer Start** and **Special Offer End**):

| Date |
| --- |
| '2022-01-01' |
| '2022-01-02' |
| '2022-01-03' |
| '2022-01-04' |
| '2022-01-05' |
| '2022-01-06' |
| '2022-01-07' |
| '2022-01-08' |
| '2022-01-09' |
| '2022-01-10' |
| '2022-01-11' |

creates:

| Shop ID | Date | Special Offer? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | '2022-01-01' | 1 |
| A | '2022-01-02' | 1 |
| A | '2022-01-03' | 1 |
| A | '2022-01-04' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-05' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-06' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-07' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-08' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-09' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-10' | NaN |
| A | '2022-01-11' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-01' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-02' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-03' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-04' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-05' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-06' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-07' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-08' | NaN |
| B | '2022-01-09' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-10' | 1 |
| B | '2022-01-11' | 1 |

EDIT:
here is the code I've written:

```
new_list = []
for i, row in sales_df.iterrows():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=row["Special Offer Start"],end=row["Special Offer End"]), columns=['Date'])
    df['Shop ID'] = row['Shop ID']
    df["Special Offer?"] = 1
    new_list.append(df)

result = pd.concat(new_list ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Instead of explaining the code, why don't you post it?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal so? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> The Shop ID column is missing

You can use `date_range` to expand the dates:

```
# Setup minimal reproducible example
data = [{'Shop ID': 'A', 'Special Offer Start': '2022-01-01', 'Special Offer End': '2022-01-03'},
        {'Shop ID': 'B', 'Special Offer Start': '2022-01-09', 'Special Offer End': '2022-01-11'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Not mandatory if you have already DatetimeIndex
df['Special Offer Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Special Offer Start'])
df['Special Offer End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Special Offer End'])

# create full date range
start = df['Special Offer Start'].min()
end = df['Special Offer End'].max()
dti = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D', name='Date')

date_range = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Special Offer Start'], x['Special Offer End'])
out = (df.assign(Offer=df.apply(date_range, axis=1), dummy=1).explode('Offer')
         .pivot_table(index='Offer', columns='Shop ID', values='dummy', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(dti, fill_value=0).unstack().rename('Special Offer?').reset_index())
```

```
>>> out
   Shop ID       Date  Special Offer?
0        A 2022-01-01               1
1        A 2022-01-02               1
2        A 2022-01-03               1
3        A 2022-01-04               0
4        A 2022-01-05               0
5        A 2022-01-06               0
6        A 2022-01-07               0
7        A 2022-01-08               0
8        A 2022-01-09               0
9        A 2022-01-10               0
10       A 2022-01-11               0
11       B 2022-01-01               0
12       B 2022-01-02               0
13       B 2022-01-03               0
14       B 2022-01-04               0
15       B 2022-01-05               0
16       B 2022-01-06               0
17       B 2022-01-07               0
18       B 2022-01-08               0
19       B 2022-01-09               1
20       B 2022-01-10               1
21       B 2022-01-11               1
```

Comment: The Shop ID column ist missing tho...

Comment: do you know how to include the ID? :)

Comment: @xstrawarot. Sorry for missing that. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Hey, sorry for responding so late your code does work! Your code definetly is a huge execution time improvement. Thank you! However I will try to use pandasql to keep it more readable and compare the runtime.